# Boxed equation in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to put an equation within a box. This equation is a label for a picture I'm making by means of pgfplots, tikzpicture environment.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.0]
\begin{loglogaxis}
    [
    title = Test,
    xlabel = {$k_{\perp}$},
    ylabel = {$k_{\parallel}$},
    xmin = 1, xmax = 1e3,
    ymin = 1, ymax = 1e3,
    legend style = {draw = none, font = \small}, legend pos = north west, %DRAW is box
    ]

\addplot[black, very thick, dashed, domain = 1e0:1e3, samples = 100]{x};
\node at(axis cs: 2e2,4e2) {\tiny \textcolor{black}{$k_{\parallel} = k_{\perp}$}};

\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The equation I wanna put in a box is the one in the `\node` command.
I've found a way to create a box but I can't use it inside the `\node` command.

```
\usepackage{empheq}
\newenvironment{boxedeq*}
  {\empheq[box=\fbox]{equation*}}
  {\endempheq}

\begin{document}
\begin{boxedeq*}
k_{\parallel} = k_{\perp}
\end{boxedeq*}
\end{document}
```

Any working solution is fine, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Will `\node[draw] at ...` work?

Comment: @darthbith You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Scz beat me to it! I was waiting for confirmation from the OP that the solution would work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Non-TikZ solutions**

There is a non-TikZ solution which will make a very tight frame:

```
\node at(axis cs: 2e2,4e2) {\frame{\tiny $k_{\parallel} = k_{\perp}$}};
```

A not-so-tight frame can be generated with `\framebox{...}`.

**TikZ solutions**
Use `\node[draw]` as mentioned in [darthbith's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256176/boxed-equation-in-pgfplots#comment613349_2561769):

```
\node[draw] at(axis cs: 2e2,4e2) {\tiny $k_{\parallel} = k_{\perp}$};
```

to get a bigger frame. The size can then be controlled with `inner sep`, e.g. `\node[draw,inner sep=1mm]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Both solutions you've provided work. Anyway the latter (thanks to @darthbith as well) is the best because of `inner sep` option. In fact the `\frame` solution is too tight as you wrote and doesn't fit properly.